# Hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /input /output doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-emr, word-count

First we create input and output files manually with `hdfs dfs -mkdir /input` and `hdfs dfs -mkdir /output`. Then we execute `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal Books /Shakespare.txt /input/Shakespare.txt`. After we run `hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /input /output` this code we get the following error:

[image: this]

Therefore we remove output and we run `hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /input /output` again we get the following error:

[image: this]

How can we get output?

Edit after Majid Hajibaba's answer:
[image: this]

Comment: Both pictures are equal. What is your error message after removing output directory?

Comment: we don't actually get an error. but we don't get a result either, it goes into an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

`WordCount.jar` will create output directory itself. Just pass it as a parameter and don't make it handy. So please remove output directory and try again. However to run WordCount.jar you need to start yarn by `start-yarn.sh` and check `ResourceManager` is up and running  by `jps` command.

It is good to know default ports on Hadoop ecosystem. See [​YARN Service Ports](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.5/bk_reference/content/yarn-ports.html).

Comment: Hi. I used your advice but i could not do it. I am not sure if i did correctly. Can you check the image what i attached to the question? And, I used jps command and i get 33727 ResourceManager but i could not find what does it mean. Thank you.

Comment: please do JPS 5 minutes after start and see which services is up. It seems your resource manager is up and running! But I cannot see `nodemanager`. What is your workers host in the `worker` file?